# Android codes for key in softkeyboard

Tags: android

I was making a keyboard and I found out that there are special keycodes for keys such as delete, done and changing from numeric to symbol keyboards and they had negative values assigned to them. Can anyone tell me what are keycodes of all keys including those of negative keys?

Answer (score 0):

Here it is

```
   -4 -->  "KEYCODE_DONE"
   -5 -->  "KEYCODE_DELETE"
   -2 -->  "KEYCODE_MODE_CHANGE"
    0 -->  "KEYCODE_0" 
    1 -->  "KEYCODE_SOFT_LEFT" 
    2 -->  "KEYCODE_SOFT_RIGHT" 
    3 -->  "KEYCODE_HOME" 
    4 -->  "KEYCODE_BACK" 
    5 -->  "KEYCODE_CALL" 
    6 -->  "KEYCODE_ENDCALL" 
    7 -->  "KEYCODE_0" 
    8 -->  "KEYCODE_1" 
    9 -->  "KEYCODE_2" 
    10 -->  "KEYCODE_3" 
    11 -->  "KEYCODE_4" 
    12 -->  "KEYCODE_5" 
    13 -->  "KEYCODE_6" 
    14 -->  "KEYCODE_7" 
    15 -->  "KEYCODE_8" 
    16 -->  "KEYCODE_9" 
    17 -->  "KEYCODE_STAR" 
    18 -->  "KEYCODE_POUND" 
    19 -->  "KEYCODE_DPAD_UP" 
    20 -->  "KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN" 
    21 -->  "KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT" 
    22 -->  "KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT" 
    23 -->  "KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER" 
    24 -->  "KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP" 
    25 -->  "KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN" 
    26 -->  "KEYCODE_POWER" 
    27 -->  "KEYCODE_CAMERA" 
    28 -->  "KEYCODE_CLEAR" 
    29 -->  "KEYCODE_A" 
    30 -->  "KEYCODE_B" 
    31 -->  "KEYCODE_C" 
    32 -->  "KEYCODE_D" 
    33 -->  "KEYCODE_E" 
    34 -->  "KEYCODE_F" 
    35 -->  "KEYCODE_G" 
    36 -->  "KEYCODE_H" 
    37 -->  "KEYCODE_I" 
    38 -->  "KEYCODE_J" 
    39 -->  "KEYCODE_K" 
    40 -->  "KEYCODE_L" 
    41 -->  "KEYCODE_M" 
    42 -->  "KEYCODE_N" 
    43 -->  "KEYCODE_O" 
    44 -->  "KEYCODE_P" 
    45 -->  "KEYCODE_Q" 
    46 -->  "KEYCODE_R" 
    47 -->  "KEYCODE_S" 
    48 -->  "KEYCODE_T" 
    49 -->  "KEYCODE_U" 
    50 -->  "KEYCODE_V" 
    51 -->  "KEYCODE_W" 
    52 -->  "KEYCODE_X" 
    53 -->  "KEYCODE_Y" 
    54 -->  "KEYCODE_Z" 
    55 -->  "KEYCODE_COMMA" 
    56 -->  "KEYCODE_PERIOD" 
    57 -->  "KEYCODE_ALT_LEFT" 
    58 -->  "KEYCODE_ALT_RIGHT" 
    59 -->  "KEYCODE_SHIFT_LEFT" 
    60 -->  "KEYCODE_SHIFT_RIGHT" 
    61 -->  "KEYCODE_TAB" 
    62 -->  "KEYCODE_SPACE" 
    63 -->  "KEYCODE_SYM" 
    64 -->  "KEYCODE_EXPLORER" 
    65 -->  "KEYCODE_ENVELOPE" 
    66 -->  "KEYCODE_ENTER" 
    67 -->  "KEYCODE_DEL" 
    68 -->  "KEYCODE_GRAVE" 
    69 -->  "KEYCODE_MINUS" 
    70 -->  "KEYCODE_EQUALS" 
    71 -->  "KEYCODE_LEFT_BRACKET" 
    72 -->  "KEYCODE_RIGHT_BRACKET" 
    73 -->  "KEYCODE_BACKSLASH" 
    74 -->  "KEYCODE_SEMICOLON" 
    75 -->  "KEYCODE_APOSTROPHE" 
    76 -->  "KEYCODE_SLASH" 
    77 -->  "KEYCODE_AT" 
    78 -->  "KEYCODE_NUM" 
    79 -->  "KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK" 
    80 -->  "KEYCODE_FOCUS" 
    81 -->  "KEYCODE_PLUS" 
    82 -->  "KEYCODE_MENU" 
    83 -->  "KEYCODE_NOTIFICATION" 
    84 -->  "KEYCODE_SEARCH" 
    85 -->  "KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE"
    86 -->  "KEYCODE_MEDIA_STOP"
    87 -->  "KEYCODE_MEDIA_NEXT"
    88 -->  "KEYCODE_MEDIA_PREVIOUS"
    89 -->  "KEYCODE_MEDIA_REWIND"
    90 -->  "KEYCODE_MEDIA_FAST_FORWARD"
    91 -->  "KEYCODE_MUTE"
    92 -->  "KEYCODE_PAGE_UP"
    93 -->  "KEYCODE_PAGE_DOWN"
    94 -->  "KEYCODE_PICTSYMBOLS"
    ...
    122 -->  "KEYCODE_MOVE_HOME"
    123 -->  "KEYCODE_MOVE_END"
```

And here is the link, for more such codes. [Android Keyboard](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/inputmethodservice/Keyboard.html) and [Android KeyEvent](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html)

Comment: i got these but I want keycodes for KEYCODE_MODE_CHANGE

Comment: I added that as well. Kindly have a look at it

Comment: is there an id for android mic button? or i need to make one

Answer (score 0):

Use
android:inputType,
android:imeOption

in your xml

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. You answered "how do I change the keyboard type for input into my view"  and the question was about making the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Just Use the `KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL` constant for finding the constant for the del key

the rest can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html) on the developer site.